# How to use Unirest php ? Need to Link Site2Sms in Mashape?

Tags: php, api, unirest, mashape

I am pure beginner to APIs.. I am doing a project and think about including Site2Sms Api to send messages. The API I wish to use is in the [link.](https://www.mashape.com/blaazetech/site2sms)

The API is calling requests with Unirest PHP Library..
Can someone give a sample page or code snippet or even idea about how to implement it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you installed Unrirest ? A good way to do this is with composer (download from `http://getcomposer.org`), then `composer search unirest` will tell you which module to install.

Comment: Have you maybe clicked on the link and RTFMed? http://unirest.io/php

Answer (score 3):

That page gives you the PHP snippet you need to use,just select it from the menu on the left. Then just install Unirest through Composer:

1. First get Composer. (google is ur friend)
2. Make a `composer.json` file with:

   {
       "require-dev": {
           "mashape/unirest-php": "2.*"
       }
   }
3. Then run:

   composer require mashape/unirest-php

Follow the instructions here: https://github.com/mashape/unirest-php

4. require composer throught autoload:

   require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

and paste code from the mashape page below the above.

Its very simple..really.

Comment: `code 
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate' in C:\wamp\www\other\vendor\mashape\unirest-php\src\Unirest\Request.php on line 394
( ! ) Exception: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate in C:\wamp\www\other\vendor\mashape\unirest-php\src\Unirest\Request.php on line 394
Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0171 239440 {main}( ) ..\index.php:0
2 0.2120 455152 Unirest\Request::get( ) ..\index.php:9
3 0.2276 464696 Unirest\Request::send( ) ..\Request.php:170
`
HELP ? @API_sheriff_orlie

Comment: the SSL error is do you not having configured your local certificate.

you can use this certificate, (or generate your own): http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem